# Change ng-repeat value using another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular JS. Here is my code

```
<div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <div  ng-repeat="city in citynames">
        <p>{{city.name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-controller="secondCtrl">
    <button ng-click="changethis()">Click Here</button>
</div>

var app=angular.module('mainApp',[]);
    app.controller('firstCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
        $scope.citynames=[{name:'Chennai',id:'1'},
            {name:'Bangalore',id:'2'},
            {name:'Hyderabad',id:'3'},
            {name:'Coimbatore',id:'4'},
            {name:'Mysore',id:'5'},
            ];
       }]);
    app.controller('secondCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
        $scope.changethis=function(){
            $scope.citynames=[{name:'Delhi',id:'1'},
            {name:'Sydney',id:'2'},
            {name:'Newyork',id:'3'},
            {name:'London',id:'4'},
            ];
        };

       }]);
```

I want to change first controller `ng-repeat` while clicking second controller `ng-click` event. But using this code its not changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each controller has a separate scope, you can either use $rootScope https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope which is a global scope or use a angular service/factory https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services to share the scope between controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Both have different scope so it is not possible in any easy manner you can use `emit` or `broadcast` method if DOM have parent child relationship between them.

or you can use `$controller` service .

```
app.controller('secondCtrl',  ['$scope','$http','$controller',function($scope,$http,$controller){
        var scopeSecond;       
    $controller("firstCtrl",{'$scope': scopeSecond})   

         $scope.changethis=function(){
                    scopeSecond.citynames=[{name:'Delhi',id:'1'},
                    {name:'Sydney',id:'2'},
                    {name:'Newyork',id:'3'},
                    {name:'London',id:'4'},
                    ];
                };

               }]);
```

Comment: is there any way to to use factory for this

Comment: ya you can use a factory

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same controller for both the ng-repeat and the click. In this way you'll hace the same $scope and in the click just change the $scope that will automatically change your ng-repeat.

Much simpler and cleaner having the functionality in just one controller in this case.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl"> 
 <div ng-repeat="city in citynames"> 
  <p>{{city.name}}</p> 
 </div> 
 <button ng-click="changethis()">Click Here</button> 
</div> 

var app=angular.module('mainApp',[]); 
app.controller('Ctrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){  
 $scope.citynames=[{name: 
  'Chennai',id:'1'}, {name:
  'Bangalore',id:'2'}, {name:
  'Hyderabad',id:'3'}, {name:
  'Coimbatore',id:'4'}, {name:
  'Mysore',id:'5'}, ]; }]); 

 $scope.changethis=function(){
  $scope.citynames=[{name:'Delhi',id:'1'}, {name:'Sydney',id:'2'}, {name:'Newyork',id:'3'}, {name:'London',id:'4'}, ]; }; }
]);
```

In this approach you have one controller to "rule them all". This is great for these times that you have similar functionalities or you are working on the same variables from the same view. I really recommend one controller per view and use the factories just when you need to persist data from one view to another.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this..

```
    var app=angular.module('mainApp',[]);
    app.controller('firstCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
        $scope.citynames=[
            {name:'Chennai',id:'1'},
            {name:'Bangalore',id:'2'},
            {name:'Hyderabad',id:'3'},
            {name:'Coimbatore',id:'4'},
            {name:'Mysore',id:'5'},
            ];

       $scope.$on("changeCities",function(){
            $scope.citynames=[{name:'Delhi',id:'1'},
               {name:'Sydney',id:'2'},
               {name:'Newyork',id:'3'},
               {name:'London',id:'4'},
            ];
       });
       }]);


    app.controller('secondCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
        $scope.$broadcast("changeCities");
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One other solution would be to use the $rootScope, but this object should not be polluted. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/idnwRWK4hZSFTqpZduVb?p=preview) you have a working example.

```
var app=angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('firstCtrl',['$rootScope','$http',function($rootScope,$http){
  $rootScope.citynames=[{name:'Chennai',id:'1'},
      {name:'Bangalore',id:'2'},
      {name:'Hyderabad',id:'3'},
      {name:'Coimbatore',id:'4'},
      {name:'Mysore',id:'5'},
      ];
 }]);

app.controller('secondCtrl',['$rootScope','$http',function($rootScope,$http){
    $rootScope.changethis=function(){
        $rootScope.citynames=[{name:'Delhi',id:'1'},
          {name:'Sydney',id:'2'},
          {name:'Newyork',id:'3'},
          {name:'London',id:'4'},
        ];
    };
}]);
```